# Does having 550 tables in MySQL slow down the performance?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know that there is no limit on the number of tables the MySQL can have and I've also come to know that it doesn't affect much.

But I want to know this. I have around 550 tables in 1 DB, and I get more than 50000 visitors to my site, does it slow down?

The site is designed in PHP and in a way that one query takes data from 1 table and leads to another query which takes the data from same table. Does it slow down with so many visits daily?

Comment: It will be slowed by executing so many queries... using JOINS might help reduce the number of queries that you need to execute

Answer (score 4):

It slows down, when you get more data in the tables or execute more (or more complex) queries. 
A table itself doesn't slow down MySQL. You can add as many tables as you like without performance penalties. More visitors (more queries) does, however.

Comment: basically speaking ...there's like a max of 2 queries like this          $query = "select DISTINCT season from '$show' ";                          and another maximum in a script nothing more complicated i have used, i echo a lot of data from the table... even then will it be slowed?

Comment: In general, the more you do, the slower it gets, although there are many optimizations possible in SQL and in PHP. But executing two simple queries even for 50.000 people (a day?) is easy for every server. Don't worry about it until you really have these number of visitors and you see an increased load on your servers.

Comment: 'Select distinct' will probably be slow; there maybe room for improvement with the queries themselves.

Comment: thnx guys....newman , its the only tag that helps me get the stuff i want lol :D...i tried a lot of things , but nothing works better than that for my case :D                                                              golez trol......i have only simple queries like that .......yes 50000 a day ......thnx again  m8